# Error LNK1112 when compiling a simple C++ program that include PyBind 11

Tags: c++, linker, pybind11

I encountered the following error when trying to compile a simple test C++ program that includes pybind11.h (shown as follows)

The errors are:
"Error- LNK1112 module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'  "

My test code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Aspose.Cells.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void print(const char*);

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

//PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
//  m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

//  m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
//}


int main()
{
    const char *x = "C Plus plus.";
    string xx = string(x);

    char *z;
    char b = 'z';
    z = &b;
    
    int num = 10;
    int* a = 0;

    print(x);
    //std::cout << "Hello!!\n";
}

void print(const char* z) 
{
    
    std::cout << "pointer z is" << z << "\n";
    

}
```

I thought I need to change the target architecture, so I made the changes as shown in the screenshot below, but I still couldn't compile. Instead of receiving the previous error message, the error became a red curly line under "#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>, where it warned "cannot open source file "pybind11/pybind11.h"".

If I I reverse all changes that were shown in the screenshots (back to W32), it compiles. But only if I "commented out" the lines for PYBIND11_MODULE. I need to use Pybind11.h , so being able to compile without the line for PYBIND11_MODULE., is not useful for me.
Can someone please help? Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

[image: Changes in Configuration Manager]
[image: Other changes]

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to link with 32bit libraries. Does your code compile when you set the platform to x86? (a.k.a Win32)

Comment: You may need to set the include dirs also in x64 platform configuration.

Comment: I just reversed all changes that were shown in the screenshots, and it compiled. But only if I "commented out" the lines for PYBIND11_MODULE. I need to use Pybind11.h , so being able to compile without the line for PYBIND11_MODULE., is not useful for me.

Comment: hi Manuel, thank you for your suggestion, Can you tell me how I can configure x64 in include dirs? sorry for asking such basic questions, I'm very new to C++

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following the instructions listed on the following webpage, in addition to the steps I mentioned in my original post concerning changes of target architecture:

https://github.com/Microsoft/python-sample-vs-cpp-extension

specifically the following two steps:
1)C++ > General > Additional Include Directories :
Property must point to the "include" folder of your Python installation.
2)Linker > General > Additional Library Directories:
Property must point to the "libs" folder of your Python installation.

For the benefits of other people who migh ran into same problems as me, below is another good list of instructions which I referred to additionally, and I found it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Unable to locate Python.h (E1696: cannot open source file "Python.h" and/or C1083: Cannot open include file: "Python.h": No such file or directory): verify that the path in C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories in the project properties points to your Python installation's include folder. See step 6 under Create the core C++ project.

Unable to locate Python libraries: verify that the path in Linker > General > Additional Library Directories in the project properties points to your Python installation's libs folder. See step 6 under Create the core C++ project.

Linker errors related to target architecture: change the C++ target's project architecture to match that of your Python installation. For example, if you're targeting x64 with the C++ project but your Python installation is x86, change the C++ project to target x86.